# how to EnumerateFiles use in 3.5 framework

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-xml

i have following query how to use this query in 3.5 framework. because i can't change my framework please help me.i am very thankful to you

```
 var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                                where line.Contains("2016-05-09 10:31:28:000 +0100")
                                select new
                                {
                                    File = file,
                                    Line = line
                                }
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-En/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx), EnumerateFiles is available since .NET Framework 4.0.

You need to replace it with **Directory.GetFiles**:

```
var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            where line.Contains("2016-05-09 10:31:28:000 +0100")
            select new
            {
                File = file,
                Line = line
            }
```

You need only be aware of difference - `GetFiles` is not lazy, so it will search and load all files paths at once into array that will be queried via linq.

Comment: Error2 'System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for 'ReadLines'

Comment: Have you managed to fix `ReadLines`? It is also not avallbe in 4.0. But There is `ReadAllLines`.